# How to add image on react-native-google-places-autocomplete list

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, react-google-places-autocomplete

I can't figure out this problem. Is it possible on this npm library?
[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pzFj.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community. If my answer worked you can accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the `renderRow` prop

> renderRow: custom component to render each result row (use this to
> show an icon beside each result). data and index will be passed as
> input parameters